# Rounding the Decimal to 1.00 and 0.10 in Android

Tags: android, decimal, rounding

As Title, how to round the decimal to 1.00 if the number is 1.01,1.02,1.03,1.04 and round the decimal to 0.10 if the number is 0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code:

```
 private static void roundOff(double num) {
    double intPart = (int) num;
    double rondededOffNum = intPart+ Math.round((num- intPart)*10)/10.0;
    System.out.println(rondededOffNum);
}
```